# How to access dialog stack in Microsoft Bot Composer

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I want access to dialog stack in bot composer which includes info like current/active dialog, next dialogs in stack.
I got chance to analyze turn scope object by using "Send a response" action like

- Print turn, ${turn}
  but its not having any such information
  Same thing I tried to achieve for dialog, conversation scope but this time it giving error as those are dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `dialogStack` in the `conversation.DialogState` property. However, accessing the property can be tricky and doesn't paint a complete picture of where the user is within a given dialog.

Using the active/current prompt will offer a more precise view of where the user is in the dialog. As prompt ids are computed values, the recommendation is to set a state variable that is continually updated in between each prompt to take the name of whichever prompt is coming next. For example, use `SetProperty` to assign `dialog.input = 'name'` before calling a named prompt.

Hope of help!